# How does the "giant mosquito", Psorophora ciliata manifest it's "aggresive and vicious" behavior?

Tags: entomology, behaviour, mosquitoes

On *Psorophora ciliata* Wikipedia states:

> Not only are these mosquitoes **vicious and aggressive towards humans**
> and other animals as adults but, P. ciliata larvae are known for
> preying on other mosquito species' larvae and even tadpoles. [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psorophora_ciliata#cite_note-Ragasa-2)

Emphasis mine.

Now every mosquito is kinda aggressive by drinking your blood and being generally annoying. So what makes *Psorophora ciliata* especially aggressive? Does it scream expletives or what does it do?

Comment: The key is "toward humans". There are so many species of mosquito, and many of them prefer other animals to feed upon. I also suspect that the Wikipedia article may have been a bit hyperbolic. My guess is that it just has a strong preference for humans. I'd put this in the answer box, but I am really just guessing.

Comment: @KarlKjer Yeah, I was also suspicious about the statement on wikipedia. But that's why I asked. Those mosquitoes have attracted some media attention, so I'm hoping some real research was done. If the statement on wikipedia is proven inflated by some scientific research we can edit it.